# Instalar Imagick PHP5.4 centOS

Tags: php, centos, imagick

Estou tentando instalar o Imagick em um servidor centOS 5.11 porém ate agora sem sucesso.

Quando executo:
`convert --version`, recebi a mensagem

> Version: ImageMagick 7.0.1-10 Q16 x86_64 2016-06-07
>   http://www.imagemagick.org Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2016
>   ImageMagick Studio LLC License:
>   http://www.imagemagick.org/script/license.php Features: Cipher DPC
>   HDRI OpenMP  Delegates (built-in): bzlib djvu fontconfig freetype jng
>   jpeg openexr pangocairo png tiff wmf x xml zlib

Quando executo `pvp -v`

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/lib64/php/modules/imagick.so' - libtiff.so.5: cannot open shared
>   object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0 PHP
>
> Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/lib64/php/modules/imagick.so' - libtiff.so.5: cannot open shared
>   object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
>
> PHP 5.4.25
>   (cli) (built: Feb 10 2014 08:04:23)  Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP
>   Group Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies

Ja desinstalei e instalei o imagick diversas vezes e nada acontece, sempre recebo o mesmo erro.

Comment: teu php é 64 ou x86?

Comment: 64, mas por curiosidade como faço para verificar isso depois de instalado?

Comment: Usando `phpinfo()`, me diz uma coisa, você compilou o imagick ou fez a instalação via repositório do teu linux?

Comment: Estou suspeitando que tem duas instalações do php na tua maquina

Comment: caso tenha, como faria para remover a mais antiga...?

Comment: Depende muito de como instalou, eu removeria tudo e instalaria de novo, é que sou usuário de `apt-get` o que não é teu caso, por isso fica dificil orientar... Diz uma coisa, você jogou o imagick diretamente na pasta `/usr/lib64/php/modules/` ou colocou na pasta ext?